# Can't use an installed library in Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I have already installed a library for oled display. Then I include this in my code with: `#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>`, but then I get an error:

> display_test:1:30: error: Adafruit_SSD1306.h: No such file or directory
>
> compilation terminated.
>
> exit status 1
>
> Adafruit_SSD1306.h: No such file or directory

This is the path to Adafruit_SSD1306.h:  `C:\Users\filip\OneDrive\Dokumente\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_SSD1306`

Full code:

```
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>

Adafruit_SSD1306 display(4); 

void setup()
{
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C); 
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);
  display.setCursor(0,15);
  display.setTextSize(2);
  display.print((char)247);
  display.print("C");
  display.display();
}
```

Comment: Post a screenshot of the contents of that folder please. Also, are you sure you're using the correct libraries folder in arduino?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Arduino IDE is looking for the library in the wrong folder. You can try importing it manually and see what happens:

```
#include "C:\Users\filip\OneDrive\Dokumente\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_SSD1306\Adafruit_SSD1306.h"
#include "C:\Users\filip\OneDrive\Dokumente\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_SSD1306\Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp"
```

When that works, try removing the library from that folder and reinstall it using the **Library Manager**. You can open the Library Manager by pressing *ctrl + shift + i*. Then just set **type** and **topic** to **all** and enter Adafruit_SSD1306 in the search bar. It will search and find the library for you, then just install.

Also, the library might be installed but not be compatible with your board (for example because it uses chip specific internal timers). So, try to find out if the library is suitable for your board.

Comment: i have installed this library using the **Library Manager**, and it automaticly installed in that folder(`C:\Users\filip\OneDrive\Dokumente\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_SSD1306`)

Comment: Sometimes the actual library files are called slightly different. Have you tried opening an example and see how it is done there?

Comment: I have opened an example, i tried to verify the code, but i get the same error

Comment: That is annoying, you can try to (re)install the newest version of Arduino.

Comment: I have reinstalled Arduino IDE but it still doesnt work. I have even tried to run this code with visual studio code, but it says me that it cant find this library.

Comment: `#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>

Adafruit_SSD1306 display(4);

void setup() {

  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
 
  display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C);

  Serial.begin(9600);

}

 

void loop() {

        display.clearDisplay();
      
        display.setTextColor(WHITE);
      
        display.setCursor(0,15);
      
        display.setTextSize(2);
      
        display.print((char)247);
      
        display.print("C");
      
        display.display();
            
}`

Comment: I meant in the original post, but it's ok. Which board are you using?

Comment: Did you also use the library manager to install **adafruit gfx**? I also had some errors of missing libraries until I installed that one as well.

Comment: Also, try this for including the library:
`#include "C:\Users\filip\OneDrive\Dokumente\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_SSD1306\Adafruit_SSD1306.h"
#include "C:\Users\filip\OneDrive\Dokumente\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_SSD1306\Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp`